# Sorbet variable array length

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I'm just starting to play around with the sorbet gem. I have a method that expects and returns an array of objects. The thing is, the length of the array is varied. How can I type check the method? I keep getting `Expected type [Object], got array of size 2`

Here's my method

```rb
sig { params(foo: Array[Object]).returns(Array[Object]) }
def bar(foo)
  # code to modify some of the attributes
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** You have a syntax error. Use `T::Array[Object]` (not `Array[Object]`).

You're using incorrect type syntax for arrays:

```rb
# typed: strict

extend T::Sig

sig { params(foo: Array[Object]).returns(Array[Object]) }
def bar(foo)
  # code to modify some of the attributes
end
```

[→ View on sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20strict%0A%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0Asig%20%7B%20params%28foo%3A%20Array%5BObject%5D%29.returns%28Array%5BObject%5D%29%20%7D%0Adef%20bar%28foo%29%0A%20%20%23%20code%20to%20modify%20some%20of%20the%20attributes%0Aend%0A)

The errors show:

```
editor.rb:5: Use T::Array[...], not Array[...] to declare a typed Array https://srb.help/5026
     5 |sig { params(foo: Array[Object]).returns(Array[Object]) }
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Note:
    Array[...] will raise at runtime because this generic was defined in the standard library
  Autocorrect: Use `-a` to autocorrect
    editor.rb:5: Replace with T::Array
     5 |sig { params(foo: Array[Object]).returns(Array[Object]) }
                                                 ^^^^^

editor.rb:5: Use T::Array[...], not Array[...] to declare a typed Array https://srb.help/5026
     5 |sig { params(foo: Array[Object]).returns(Array[Object]) }
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Note:
    Array[...] will raise at runtime because this generic was defined in the standard library
  Autocorrect: Use `-a` to autocorrect
    editor.rb:5: Replace with T::Array
     5 |sig { params(foo: Array[Object]).returns(Array[Object]) }
                          ^^^^^
Errors: 2
```

---

Why is it like this?

The `[]` method on `Array` has special meaning, but Sorbet uses `[]` for generic type arguments. To get around that, Sorbet uses the `T::` namespace for certain generic classes in the standard library:

→ https://sorbet.org/docs/stdlib-generics

What's happening in your case is that this code:

```
Array[Object]
```

is equivalent to having written this:

```
[Object]
```

(i.e., "make an array of length one containing the value `Object`"). `[Object]` in Sorbet happens to be the way to express a `1-tuple`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. I'm so new to sorbet, I forgot to run `srb tc` once I did, I saw your fix in the suggested corrections. Thanks again :D